# What is the size, volume, dimensions etc. of the central lateral nucleus in the anterior intralaminar thalamus in humans?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, neurophysiology, brain, neuroanatomy

I have been searching extensively on the internet and journal articles for the size, volume, dimensions, etc. of the central lateral nucleus in the anterior intralaminar thalamus in humans but have not been to find any information? Could anybody point me to a source that contains this information or anything relevant (e.g., about the anterior intralaminar nuclei in general)?

Thanks!